# jQuery Two functions, same result, same element

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery functions on same element with same result. Is there a way to have a shorter code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').dblclick(function(){
        if($('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').is(':visible')){
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
        }else{
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
            $('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').show();
            $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').addClass('t_ar');
        }
    })
    $('#td_arrow_down_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').click(function(){
        if($('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').is(':visible')){
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
        }else{
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
            $('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').show();
            $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').addClass('t_ar');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It is pretty simple you should create function and gave this function as input variable to event handler function. (i.e. .dbclick(), .click() and etc.). Since function also object in javasript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').dblclick(do_action_name);
    $('#td_arrow_down_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').click(do_action_name);

    function do_action_name()
    {
        if($('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').is(':visible'))
        {
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
            $('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').show();
            $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').addClass('t_ar');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I must admit I saw something similar but I still don't know how to do it in this case.

Comment: The parentheses should be removed: `.dblclick(do_action_name);` and `.click(do_action_name);`, otherwise you pass the result of `do_action_name()`, in stead of the function itself, to the event handlers.

Comment: Yeap, that's it.
My bad part was I created my function outside of document ready. Or who knows why... but it was not working. Now it is. Thank you! Voted up!

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and bind it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction(){
        if($('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').is(':visible')){
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
        }else{
            $('.tlistd').hide();
            $('.tlist').removeClass('t_ar');
            $('#taskd_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').show();
            $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').addClass('t_ar');
        }
    }
    $('#task_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').dblclick(myFunction);
    $('#td_arrow_down_<?php echo $var_t; ?>').click(myFunction);
});
```

Comment: there is a semicolon after the first call